# From a list of objects containing year and decimal, add object with highest decimal for each year to a new list

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have a class Region

```
public class Region
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Participation> Participations { get; set; }
}
```

I have a class Participation

```
public class Participation
{
    public string Year { get; set; }
    public decimal? ParticipationPercentage { get; set; }
    public string RegionId { get; set; }
    public Region Region { get; set; }
}
```

There are multiple years and multiple entries for each year, but I want to grab only the region with the highest decimal for each year, repeating for each region and adding it to a new list. So if the year 1950 has 10 entries I want only the one with the highest decimal of all of them, or both if there's a tie. I have all the regions stored in a variable.

```
var regions = await GetRegionList();

IList<Region> TopRegions = new List<Region>();
```

I'm not sure if I should use regular expressions or LINQ, but I haven't made much progress with either. I tried using the `Max()` method in a regular expression but was not allowed on decimal, and I'm not sure how to use the `decimal.Round()` with regular expressions.

Comment: Can you solve this problem without regular expressions or LINQ? I'd start there, since it sounds like you're not too familiar with regular expressions or LINQ. (Regular expressions won't help here BTW, nor will `Round()`.)

Comment: Wouldn't the result type need to be a list of tuples where the tuple consisted of (a) the year, (b) the max participation percentage for that year and (c) the list of regions with participations matching that maximum?  If it was just a list of regions, then you wouldn't know which region was top for which year after all the calculations are done.  Unless you don't care?  Is this just meant to be a filter of the original list?

Comment: @srk I think I just figured out something else to try that doesn't involve LINQ or regular expressions actually

Comment: @BrianRogers Yes exactly, this is just to filter the original list, I'll perform further calculation on the new list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirements are not very clearly written, but I *think* this is what you are ultimately looking for:

```
IList<Region> TopRegions = regions
    .SelectMany(r => r.Participations)
    .GroupBy(p => p.Year)
    .Select(g =>
    {
        var max = g.Max(p => p.ParticipationPercentage);
        return g.Where(p => p.ParticipationPercentage == max)
                .Select(p => p.Region);
    })
    .SelectMany(r => r)
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

This takes the original list of regions, flattens it into a list of all participations, groups that list by year, then for each year finds the max participation percentage and the list of regions having participations matching that max for that year.  Finally that list of lists of regions is flattened back to a single list and the duplicates are removed, leaving a plain list of distinct regions representing the "top regions".

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/W2JKUy

Answer (score 1):

the question is not clear, but here is an example by regular expression.

```
public void RegionTest()
    {
        var region1 = new Region() { Id = "L001", Name = "Local1", Participations = new List<Participation>() };
        var region2 = new Region() { Id = "L002", Name = "Local2", Participations = new List<Participation>() };
        var region3 = new Region() { Id = "L003", Name = "Local3", Participations = new List<Participation>() };

        var participant1 = new Participation() { Year = "2000", ParticipationPercentage = 90, RegionId = "A001", Region = region1 };
        var participant2 = new Participation() { Year = "2000", ParticipationPercentage = 85, RegionId = "A002", Region = region2 };
        var participant3 = new Participation() { Year = "2000", ParticipationPercentage = 80, RegionId = "A003", Region = region3 };
        var participant4 = new Participation() { Year = "2001", ParticipationPercentage = 70, RegionId = "B004", Region = region1 };
        var participant5 = new Participation() { Year = "2001", ParticipationPercentage = 80, RegionId = "B005", Region = region2 };

        region1.Participations = new List<Participation>() { participant1, participant4};
        region2.Participations = new List<Participation>() { participant2, participant5 };

        var topRegions = new List<Region>();
        var list1 = new List<decimal?>();
        var list2 = new List<decimal?>();

        foreach (var region in region1.Participations)
        {
            list1.Add(region.ParticipationPercentage);
            if ( region.ParticipationPercentage >= list1.Max())
            { topRegions.Add(region.Region); } 
        }
        foreach (var region in region2.Participations)
        {
            list2.Add(region.ParticipationPercentage);
            if (region.ParticipationPercentage >= list2.Max())
            { topRegions.Add(region.Region); }
        }
}
```

Comment: OH you meant that Regex class...!